# Unable to find expected number of element in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

When search element in chrome using inspect element search box by xpath '//*[contains(@id,'a')]' then total found element number is 43 but when use the same xpath in selenium code then it shows only 37 element found.

below is selenium code. I even tried looking into frame but still did not get expected result

```
driver.get("http://facebook.com");
        //System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.tagName("iframe")).size());
        List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'a')]"));
        System.out.println(a.size());
        driver.switchTo().frame(0);
        List<WebElement>b=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'a')]"));
        System.out.println(b.size());
        driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
        driver.switchTo().frame(1);
        List<WebElement>c=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'a')]"));
        System.out.println(c.size());
        driver.switchTo().parentFrame();
```

Comment: How are those element being created? Maybe you need to make selenium wait until all elements are created.

Comment: Selenium get(url) command waits until all elements are loaded. So not sure waiting is the option

Comment: But maybe those elements are being updated via an API call to somewhere else. I have been in a similar situation.

Comment: I am new to Java and selenium so could not get exactly what you mentioned. but if what you are saying is true the what is the solution

Comment: Try this line of code. We will figure out if it's timing or not. driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: I tried thread.sleep(30000) after loading the page and before moving to other frames but still count is 38

Comment: I noticed one thing after searching element in browser when i move to element 37, it does not get highlighted . same for all elements from 37 to 43

Comment: Can you copy and paste those elements in HTML code?

Comment: Is there a way i can copy all the html code from element section of browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The reason you are getting a different number of nodes is in the DOM there are `iframe` elements. There is even an `iframe` inside an `iframe`.
- When you are searching in the chrome dev tools, it shows all elements, including the ones inside the frames.
  But when you are using selenium, it is not accessing the DOM inside the frames.
  That is why you are getting fewer elements in selenium.
- When you are switching the frames you are not actually searching it in all the second-degree frames available in the page.

I've identified the frames in which the missing elements are. Just don't go back to the parent frame and go another level deeper and you'll find all your elements.

Try the following code and it will give you the desired result.

```
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com");

    List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'a')]"));
    System.out.println("Main Page: "+list.size());

    //driver.switchTo().frame("captcha-recaptcha");
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    List<WebElement> list2 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'a')]"));
    System.out.println("In the iFrame: "+list2.size());

    //driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("body > div.g-recaptcha > div > div > iframe")));
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    List<WebElement> list3 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'a')]"));
    System.out.println("In the second iFrame: "+list3.size());

    System.out.println("Full count: "+(list.size()+list2.size()+list3.size()));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it helped